# Proof that a countable infinite set A is in bijective correspondence with the natural numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]

I follow the majority of this proof (please see image) but could someone please explain what the map alpha is actually doing in a different way as I am a bit confused? Thanks!

Comment: Other than "it counts the elements $C$ that are smaller or equal to $c$"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example may help. Suppose $C$ is the set of prime numbers. The we have that, for a prime $c$, the function $\alpha$ counts how many primes are $\le c$. Thus:

$\alpha(2)=1\\
\alpha(3)=2\\
\alpha(5)=3\\
\alpha(7)=4\\
\alpha(11)=5$

etc.

Comment: Okay right yeah that makes sense, so it's a function that we can be certain is a bijection to the naturals no matter what C actually is?

Is it not a sufficient proof of the bijection before we get to that stage seeing as we know the cardinality of C and the naturals are both infinite?

Comment: What is the definition of "countable infinite set" that precedes this proof? The answer to "why is this step necessary?" depends on exactly where we're starting.

Comment: Fair enough, this is the first time countably infinite sets have occurred in this course. I just thought that seeing as it's already stated that C is an infinite set and we know the naturals are infinite that would prove there is a bijective relationship between the two. Should I just take it as the last bit being a more thorough proof?

Comment: Yeah, not all infinite sets are in bijection with each other. All *countable* infinite sets are, and this is a proof of that fact. This looks like it comes out of a book? Which one?

Comment: It looks like your book has defined "countable set" as a set that has an injection into $\Bbb N$. Maybe you can find that in the text immediately preceding this theorem.

Comment: Okay that makes a lot more sense, thank you! 

Yeah that's right, I'm just getting a bit muddled as I'm really trying to thoroughly grasp all the details so I have a good base to learn from. They are provided by my lecturer but I think it's an extract from his book "Introductory Mathematics: Algebra and Analysis". Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If $C$ is a subset of $\mathbb N$ and $c\in C$, then $\alpha(x)=\#\{c'\in C\,|\,c'\leqslant c\}$. I other words, $\alpha(c)$ is the number of elements of $C$ which are smaller than or equal to $c$. The map $\alpha$ is a bijection if and only if $C$ is infinite.